# How do I add the 'Turn Off Computer' button to RocketDock?

Tags: windows-xp, rocketdock

I'm running Windows XP with [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/).

I want to add a button/icon to my dock that acts in the same way as clicking the 'Turn Off Computer' button in the Start menu i.e. so it brings up the 'Standby, Turn off, Restart' dialogue box.

I currently have a button on my dock that turns off my computer and another one that restarts it but I just want one to bring up the 'Standby, Turn off, Restart' box so I have the usual choice (and can save a button at the same time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open Notepad or any text editor you use.
2. Copy the following single line to the text: 
   `(new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")).ShutdownWindows();`
3. Save as "Shutdown.js" (without the quotes) anywhere you like on your computer.
4. Create a new shortcut that points to Shutdown.js.

Comment: That did it - thanks! 

Any other code snippets like this that do useful things in RocketDock?

Comment: That's all I got :D

Comment: +1 for not using `rundll32` for that.

Answer (score 2):

IF you download Wizmo at Steve Gibson's http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm site, you can get a lot of little things like Reboot and Shutdown routines. I use it's 'screen saver' too. All can be added to a RocketDock or any other app launcher.